# Taking information from a MS Access form with text boxes and send the information to an excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

So i have an MS Access form that with predefined fields that are linked to different tables in my MS Access DB. What i want to do is take the information from each textbox in the form and make that into a spread sheet in excel and then save that to a predefined folder. I currently have no code and i am not sure how to execute this. I am trying to keep all the code tied to a button on the form so that you can load the form and then press the button.

not sure what else to include but i am using MS Access 2013 and Excel 2013.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a very broad question and you will not get specific code. You want to export a single record that is displayed on form? Pulling values from form as opposed to exporting a table or query or report will require complicated code. Best approach is to develop a query or simple report that presents the desired data and then export. Here is a good site to start with http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_MainPage.htm

Comment: agreed it is a broad question, thank you for the starting point as i had no idea where to start. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong command

```
 Private Sub this()
     DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "form name", acFormatXLS, "C:\Users\dcoats\Desktop\filename.xls"
End Sub
```

Comment: so would i take each individual field from the access form and add them to the has field name? There are over 15 cols and 25 rows of individual text boxes.

Comment: No. You should do research on use of the TransferSpreadsheet command and it's arguments. That (True/False) parameter is for import operation to indicate whether or not the range includes worksheet header row. Google is your friend. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's like this........if you mean an actual form in datasheet view, you can export that form's data to Excel with the DoCmd.OutputTo method.

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "frmResults", acFormatXLS, _
    "C:\your_path_here\ExportedResults.xls"
```

However, if you're opening a query in datasheet view, rather than an actual form, you can export the query's result set.

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qryResults", acFormatXLS, _
    "C:\your_path_here\ExportedResults.xls"
```